# Stripe setup product with different fixed prices on basis of volume

Tags: stripe-payments

I am planning to sell different plans on my website using Stripe, in which one plan can have multiple prices. Pricing is on the basis of the number of project user can create. The number of projects selection is fixed, i.e 5, 10, 15, and so on,  but users can`t buy plans with projects number expect 5,10,15 and so on. I am using stripe checkout with spring boot and react. Can you please suggest who should I setup product in stripe for this scenario.

e.g

**Valid Project Allowed in plan**

```
5 projects - $10 
10 projects - $18 
15 projects - $26
```

**InValid Project Allowed in plan**

```
2 projects
8 projects 
12 projects
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to always charge $2 per project, as such I'd create a single Price for $2 and specify a quantity in your line items when creating a Checkout Session.

For example for a customer who wants 10 projects:

```js
line_items: [
  {price: 'price_123', quantity: 10},
],
```

The above will show "Projects x 10" on the Checkout page, charging your customer $20.

This way you set the quantity yourself, meaning you don't get invalid project allowances.

Comment: yes this can be an option but this is dummy data, in some case it can be like 5 projects - $8 
10 projects - $18 
15 projects - $29  . Editing the question as well